# Homogeneous differential equation - cannot manipulate equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

this was a problem from a textbook:

> > If $x>0$, $y>0$, find the general solution to the differential equation, 
> >     $$ x \frac{dy}{dx} = y + \frac{x}{\ln y - \ln x }$$ 
> >     giving your answer in the form  $ye^{y/x}=f(x)$

I approached with the substitution $y=vx$ since this is a homogenous equation. Giving,

$$ x\frac{dv}{dx}+v = v+ \frac{1}{\ln v}$$

By separating variables yields,

$$ v \ln v -v = \ln x + C $$

The by taking the power of $e$ 
$$e^{v \ln v - v } = xA$$

where $e^C= A$. This is equivalent to

$$e^{-v}v^{v} = Ax$$

Now when I substitute the value of $v= \frac{y}{x}$ back, I cannot obtain the equation of the form $ye^{y/x} = f(x)$.

Maybe I have done a mistake in my calculations. May someone explain where? Or how to solve the problem? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Everything looks fine to me in your solution.

Comment: The problem is I cannot manipulate the equation back to the desired form of the problem: $ye^{y/x} = f(x)$

Comment: Maybe you can use the Lambert W function, but I don't know all its properties ..:)

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution ( maybe someone can find something more simple).

Using the substitution $\log y-\log x=t \iff y=xe^t$
the differential equation become:
$$
te^t\,dt=\dfrac{dx}{x}
$$
with solution:
$$
e^t(t-1)=\log x +c
$$
divide by $e$:
$$
(t-1)e^{t-1}=\dfrac{\log x+c}{e}
$$
and using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) we find:
$$
t-1=W\left(\dfrac{\log x+c}{e}\right)
$$
so we have (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Identities))
$$
e^t=\dfrac{y}{x}=\dfrac{\log x +c}{W\left(\dfrac{\log x+c}{e}\right)}=e\dfrac{\dfrac{\log x +c}{e}}{W\left(\dfrac{\log x+c}{e}\right)}=
$$
$$
=ee^{W\left(\dfrac{\log x+c}{e}\right)}=F(x)
$$
and $y=xF(x)$ is the solution of the differential equation.

If we want the form requested in OP we can do:
$$
ye^{\frac{y}{x}}=xF(x)e^{F(x)}
$$